# Convert a column to timedelta and remove days from it

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am trying to convert a column with data like this: 1:38:17 or 36:21 to timedelta format. This column is extracted from a website and converted to a table using pandas.

```
df[' Chip Time'] = df[' Chip Time'].apply(pd.to_timedelta, errors='coerce')
```

This returns 0 days 01:38:17 but for rows with minutes and seconds (36:21) it returns NaT.
I would like to have the time properly converted and remove the days part leaving only the time like this: 01:38:17.

I tried using the code below but it doesn't strip the days but it strips the time.

```
df[' Chip Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df[' Chip Time'].dt.days, unit='d')
```

Please is there another method I can use in order to return a result like this 01:38:17.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. It'd help to provide a sample of the data and your desired output in Pandas format. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). See also [mre]. For general tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead of `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df[' Chip Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[' Chip Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I received a traceback error 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data ' 36:21' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: This is due to having multiple different formats in your column. Run it with `pd.to_datetime(df[' Chip Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors="ignore").dt.time` first and then a second time with `pd.to_datetime(df[' Chip Time'], format='%M:%S',  errors="ignore").dt.time`. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Hi, I received this error 
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: `df[' Chip Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[' Chip Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors="ignore")` then `df[' Chip Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[' Chip Time'], format='%M:%S',  errors="ignore")` then run `df[' Chip Time'] = df[' Chip Time'].dt.time`

Comment: I tried the code but it returns the same values instead of correcting them